# Downloading zip file using JS window.open _self without "useless window"

Tags: javascript, download

Following information from **[this page](http://pixelscommander.com/en/javascript/javascript-file-download-ignore-content-type/)** where the issue of the "useless empty window" is discussed, I'm trying to create a script that starts the download of a zip file:

```
<script>window.open('archive.zip','_self')</script>
```

The above starts the download correctly but the page is then completely blank, no content visible. I can see the entire source is loaded but not displayed.

How can I use js to start the download asynchronously while loading page content, without a "useless window"?

Comment: where have you implemented it ? can you show a live example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hidden iframe instead. The window.open will clear all your page content when using _self.

Here is a quick example

```
<a href="archive.zip" target="download_frame">Initiate download from link</a>
<iframe id="download_frame" name="download_frame" src="about:Blank" style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // initiate download by script
    // add this in onload event or after the iframe
    document.getElementById('download_frame').src="archive.zip";
</script>
```