# File download with Ext JS 6

Tags: java, spring, file, extjs, download

I'm trying to download a file from the server with an Ext JS 6 component based on this post: [download a file via Ext js 4](http://quispiam.com/download-a-file-via-an-event-for-extjs4/)

This is the component code:

```
Ext.define('Aft.view.search.FileDownload', {
extend: 'Ext.Component',
alias: 'widget.acw-fileDownload',
autoEl: {
    tag: 'iframe',
    cls: 'x-hidden',
    src: Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL
},
load: function(config){
    var e = this.getEl();
    e.dom.src = config.url +
        (config.params ? '?' + Ext.urlEncode(config.params) : '');
    e.dom.onload = function() {
        if(e.dom.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].wholeText == '404') {
            console.
            Ext.create('Acw.view.commons.notifications.Error', {
                html: 'The document you are after can not be found on the server.',
                closeAll: true
            }).show();
        }
    }
}
});
```

This is the call to get the file:

```
doExportData: function(){
    this.getView().load({
        url: '/aft/faults/download-file'

});
```

And this is the Spring rest service returning a mock file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download-file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void downloadFilePost(HttpServletResponse response) {

    String csvFileName = "searchFaults.csv";
    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    // creates mock data
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", csvFileName);
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    try {
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(response.getWriter(), '\t');
        String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
        writer.writeNext(entries);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

However when I do the call I get something like this:

> [E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: "first"    "second"    "third"
>   Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: "first"   "second"    "third"

It seems that something arrives to the client, but it is trying to parse it as JSON. In spite of this, if I change the RequestMethod to GET and I type the URL directly in the browser I get the file and that makes me think that the header is right.

Could someone help me with this issue, or are you using a different approach/component to download files from the server?

Comment: Curious why you're using an iframe and not just using `window.open`

Comment: The idea is to download it in the same page, instead of opening a new tab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288187/downloading-zip-file-using-js-window-open-self-without-useless-window

Comment: With the proper headers from the server, you don't need to use an iframe or `window.open` even. Have a link or change `window.location` and the browser will detect the headers and instead of navigating away from your app, it'll just download the file.

Comment: As you say, the iframe is not needed, with this line of code in doExportData you achieve the same:  window.location.assign(config.url + (config.params ? '?' + Ext.urlEncode(config.params) : ''));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file can be downloaded just with this code:

```
doExportData: function(config){
    window.location.assign(config.url + 
   (config.params ? '?' + Ext.urlEncode(config.params) : ''));
});
```